# Xpath Expression to filter an element

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml which looks like this:
And what I want is the value of d2 when d1 is 1st Price. This has to be a one done in one shot and not using for:each. Am stuck here as I some time need 2nd Price also.

```
<a>
<b>
.
</b>
<c>
<d>
<d1>1st Price</d1>
<d2>12</d2>
</d>
<d>
<d1>2nd Price</d1>
<d2>25</d2>
</d>
</c>
</a>
```

My initial approach was ns:c/ns:d[(ns:d1='1st Price')]/ns:d2 But am getting an error for this. Can any one please help!!

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: I was not able to get the correct value but I finally got :/a/c/d[d1/text() = '1st Price']/d2/text()

Answer (score 1):

use any one of following

```
/a/c/d[d1='1st Price']/d2 

//d[d1='1st Price']/d2

//d/d2[../d1='1st Price']
```